# Extracting text from nested HTML lists <ul> <li>

Tags: pattern-matching, html, trees, parsing

We wish to analyze the tree structure of HTML documents that consist of nested lists, ie, using the HTML tags `<ul>` and `<li>`. The documents are generated by [Workflowy](http://workflowy.com), a note taking web app that can manage arbitrarily deep nesting (and dynamically re-arrange them by zooming and searching).

For example, here's a portion of one document:

```html
<ul class="ul1">
  <li class="li2">Subjective</li>
  <ul class="ul1">
    <li class="li2">XX yr old man here for fu on med problems</li>
    <li class="li2">feels absolutely positively wonderful</li>
  </ul>
  <li class="li2">Active problems</li>
  <ul class="ul1">
    <li class="li2">htn</li>
    <ul class="ul1">
      <li class="li2">started on hctz in 8/10, in early 11 given lasix as his gfr was low</li>
      <li class="li2">limits salt caffeine, home readings140/80  or less when he runs</li>
      <li class="li2">not been exercising now</li>
    </ul>
```

After applying the main parse function in Leonid Shifrin's [HTML parser](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/jMICGBQ1EEw) (Thanks for that), the above portion is transcoded to:

```
ulContainer[attribContainer[ class="ul1"],
  ,liContainer[attribContainer[ class="li2"],Subjective],
  ,ulContainer[attribContainer[ class="ul1"],
    ,liContainer[attribContainer[ class="li2"],XX yr old man here for fu on med problems],
    ,liContainer[attribContainer[ class="li2"],feels absolutely positively wonderful],
  ],
  ,liContainer[attribContainer[ class="li2"],Active problems],
  ,ulContainer[attribContainer[ class="ul1"],
    ,liContainer[attribContainer[ class="li2"],htn],
    ,ulContainer[attribContainer[ class="ul1"],
      ,liContainer[attribContainer[ class="li2"],started on hctz in 8/10, in early 11 given lasix as his gfr was low],
      ,liContainer[attribContainer[ class="li2"],limits salt caffeine, home readings140/80  or less when he runs],
      ,liContainer[attribContainer[ class="li2"],not been exercising now],
    ],
```

Shifrin writes:

> What it gives you is a symbolic tree representation of the parsed html
>   document, with different tags transformed into ...Container[content],
>   for example divContainer[aContainer["Some text"]]. The container names
>   mirror the html tag names, except for attribContainer which is for tag
>   attributes. Also, without post-processing, no information is lost

What is required is a method to strip the markup and extract the text data as strings into a nested list expression preserving the (tree) structure. Thus for the above portion, the desired output is:

```
 {"Subjective",
    {"XX yr old man here for fu on med problems",
     "feels absolutely positively wonderful"},
  "Active problems",
    {"htn",
         {"started on hctz in 8/10, in early 11 given lasix as his gfr was low",
          "limits salt caffeine, home readings140/80  or less when he runs",
          "not been exercising now"}}}
```

I made the entire HTML document available online:

```
parsed = postProcess@
   parseText[
    Import["http://statigrafix.com/projects/pace/datasets/20130527/\
NOTES.001-01.0.WORKFLOWY.20130527.html", "TEXT"]];
```

From manually analyzing the example () and following the tree structure, it's easy to extract at the top level, eg:

```
Column@Cases[parsed[[1, 5, 5]], 
  liContainer[attribContainer[_], txt_] :> txt]

(*
Subjective
Active problems
General health
Past medical and surgical history
DA
Medications
8/08  Family History
8/08  Personal and social history
Habits
Exam
Labs
Clinical Reminder Activity
*)
```

I would appreciate help with the method to automate extraction at all levels.

Comment: What is wrong with the following? `data = Import["http://statigrafix.com/projects/pace/datasets/20130527/NOTES.001-01.0.WORKFLOWY.20130527.html", {"HTML", "XMLObject"}];` then `Cases[data, XMLElement["body", ___], \[Infinity]] //. 
 XMLElement[_, _, content_] :> content`

Comment: I did not know about HTML --> XMLObject conversion, Thanks. Your pattern does exctract the data, however, it doesn't seem to be preserving the tree structure. Eg, check the Dimensions  . We're looking to preserve the nesting.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  It does preserve the tree structure precisely as it is in the HTML.  The code needs to be improved a bit to get rid of extra nesting, but the structure is precisely preserved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefit of using a symbolic tree representation with inert heads as in Leonid's parser is that *you* can then decide how to represent the data. And that is indeed what you should do, instead of extracting the elements using `Cases`. Here's an example using your parsed output above:

```
Block[{ulContainer, liContainer},
    ulContainer[_, l__] := {l};
    liContainer[_, s_String] := s;
    parsedExpr /. Null -> Sequence[]
]
```

where `parsedExpr` is as in the question. This gives you:

```
{   
    "Subjective", 
    {
        "XX yr old man here for fu on med problems", 
        "feels absolutely positively wonderful"
    }, 
    "Active problems", 
    {
        "htn", 
        {
            "started on hctz in 8/10,in early 11 given lasix as his gfr was low", 
            "limits salt caffeine,home readings140/80 or less when he runs", 
            "not been exercising now"
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that this preserves the tree structure.